# failed to get the new value in KVO observer method

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
    #import "USST_Test.h"

    @implementation USST_Test
     -(void) observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)KeyPath  ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)
     change context:(void *) context{
        NSLog(@"yes i have been changed",nil);

    NSLog(@"%@",[change objectForKey:@"new"]);


}
-(void)setFirstName:(NSString *)firstName{


    [self addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"firstName" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];
}

@end
```

Here is my code and I always get NSNull printed.
I am new to Objective-c and any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to implement custom setter for this. 
Somewhere when you init the UUST_Test class call

```
[self addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"firstName" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];
```

And remove

```
-(void)setFirstName:(NSString *)firstName{


[self addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"firstName" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];
```

}

But be careful to remove the observer when the UUST_Test object will be destroyed. For that you can implement `-(void)dealloc` method but do NOT call `[super dealloc]` if you are using ARC which I think you use.

Comment: And if you're unsure if you're using ARC, go ahead and try to call `[super dealloc]`. It won't let you if you are, so it can't hurt to check. (Although, you should know if you aren't, since you'd be doing memory management manually.)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that you understand the purpose of KVO. You're having an object observe itself every time the first name is changed. Typically, another object would add an observer once, using a call like this:

```
[object addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"firstName" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];
```

This means that `self` would like to be informed when `object` changes its `firstName` key. Calling `[object setFirstName:name]` will automatically trigger the KVO update, so no extra code is needed in it.